# Named singleton instance in StructureMap (Multiple nHibernate session factories)

Tags: nhibernate, structuremap

I have a scenario where I have two Nhibernate SessionFactorys I need to register an use with StructureMap. Only Foo needs mySessionFactory sessions.

Like this:

```
For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(NHibernateConfiguration.GetDefaultSessionFactory());
For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(AnotherNHibernateConfiguration.GetDefaultSessionFactory).Named("mySessionFactory");
For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>("mySessionFactory").OpenSession()).Named("mySession");

For<Foo>()
   .Use<Foo>()
   .Ctor<ISession>("session").Is(x => x.TheInstanceNamed("mySession"));
```

The problem is that mySessionFactory is now used everywhere when I only wanted to to be used in Foo and everywhere else should use my unnamed instance.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On both your named instances, change `Use` to `Add`.  Use sets that instance as the default as well as adding it as an instance.  You could also reverse the order of your config (the last instance of a type added with Use will become the default), but using the `Add` method is much more explicit.